# Error while uploading gifs

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I'm able to upload any image with this code but when I try to upload gif I get an error.
Here is how I trying and the error that I get is `Error 2: ERROR upload file`. This is on the second IF block. What can be wrong here?

```
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 20000000000);
$permitted = array('image/jpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {

$caption = $_POST['caption'];
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
$category = $_POST['gif_cat'];

$ext = substr(strrchr($fileName, "."), 1);
// generate the random file name
$randName = md5(rand() * time());

// gif name with extension
$myFile = $randName . '.' . $ext;
// save gif path
$path = "../upload/gifs/" . $myFile;

if (in_array($fileType, $permitted) && $fileSize > 0
    && $fileSize <= MAX_FILE_SIZE) {

    $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $path);

    if (!$result) {
        echo "Error uploading gif file";
        exit;
    } else {
        $db = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "table");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s<br/>", mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        mysqli_set_charset($db, "UTF8");

        $query = "INSERT INTO gifs (caption, name, size, type, file_path, gif_cat) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $conn = $db->prepare($query);
        if ($conn == TRUE) {
            $conn->bind_param("ssisss",$caption, $myFile, $fileSize, $fileType, $path, $category);
            if (!$conn->execute()) {
                echo 'error insert';
            } else {
                echo "Gif {$_FILES['userfile']['name']} was successfully uploaded<br />
                <a href='index.php'>Add another gif</a><br />";
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            die("Error 1: ERROR preparing Statement");
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Error 2: ERROR upload file';
}
} else {
echo 'Error 3';
}
```

var_dump($_FILES)

```
array (size=1)
'userfile' => 
array (size=5)
  'name' => string 'azbRWYK_460sa.gif' (length=17)
  'type' => string '' (length=0)
  'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
  'error' => int 1
  'size' => int 0
```

UPDATE:

This is happen with .gifs bigger than 1MB .. I was able to upload < 1MB gif.

UPDATE 2:
That strange. On phpinfo() result is

```
max_file_uploads    20  20
post_max_size   8M  8M
upload_max_filesize 2M  2M
```

but in my php.ini I have

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
max_file_uploads - I don't have this in php.ini?!
```

How I have this differences? And where to find this second php.ini?

UPDATE 3:

Ok, I found another php.ini in apache folder and after I change values now is work. I never thought of second php.ini file.

Comment: Print the $_FILES['userfile']['type'], it might not be the allowed one

Comment: This is happen with .gifs bigger than 1MB .. I was able to upload < 1MB gif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your php.ini file and `phpinfo()` what will return and if they equal. Check if you have more than one php.ini file.

I had the same problem before and it turned out that this is the reason.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this part of your `if` statement is getting failed and this you are taking to the `Error 2: ERROR upload file` block.

```
  if (in_array($fileType, $permitted) && $fileSize > 0
        && $fileSize <= MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
```

Make a `var_dump()` of the variables `$fileType` and `$fileSize` and see if they satisfy your `if` condition.

Comment: I can't figured out why this part failed since `$filetype` and `$permitted` is ok.. I edited my question and added result from var_dump.

Comment: See your `$fileType` is just an empty variable and that's why your code fails. Also you don't need to `var_dump` the `$permitted` variable as we already know it (what is inside of it) through the code. You need to `var_dump` the `$fileSize` actually too.

Comment: `var_dump($fileSize)` return 0 `int 0`

Comment: `0 > 0` Condition still fails. It's better to `var_dump` your `$_FILES` array itself.

Comment: updated my question with `var_dump($_FILES)` and still don't know why is this

Comment: This is happen with .gifs bigger than 1MB .. I was able to upload < 1MB gif.

Comment: Did you check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size) thread how to set limit ?

Comment: Yes, both are 20MB in my php.ini. Strange but I was able to upload just one gif. Every next doesn't matter how big is doesn't upload. And on var_dump I get proper info `'size' => int 487861` and other are ok. I don't know what else can be..

Comment: So the problem is with .gif's bigger than 1MB